# Which part of code will be cached by the browser on an HTML file including PHP and Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, html, caching, browser

So i want to know which part of code will be cached by the browser if i have an HTML file which contains also PHP and JavaScript code.

Am posting below code just my question to be approved :

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>

<div> Hello </div>

<script>Hello</script>
```

Comment: The php code is executed on the server side (correct setup required, of course), so the client never sees that code. The HTML markup _can_ be cached, if the browser choses to and if the headers to not prevent caching. Same with css and js.

Comment: Does the browser automatically cache the html , javascript and css part or i need to do something in server ?

Comment: Didn't I answer that already? Yes, the browser can chose to cache content. And modern browsers usually will do so out of performance reasons. You can easily check that yourself: load your page, then open the browser's console, enter the same URL and hit enter, check what you see in the networking console. Typically you will see that most content is loaded from the local cache.